# Why is this '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsrangeexception

Why I am getting a MSRangeException with this code:

```
NSArray *patientenVornamen = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Michael", @"Thomas", @"Martin", nil];
NSArray *patientenNachnamen = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Miller", @"Townsend", @"Mullins", nil];
NSArray *patientenWeiblich = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NO, NO, NO , nil];
NSArray *patientenGeburtsdatum = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDate date], [NSDate date], [NSDate date], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Patient *patient = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Patient" inManagedObjectContext:_coreDataHelper.context];
    patient.vorname = [patientenVornamen objectAtIndex:i];
    patient.nachname = [patientenNachnamen objectAtIndex:i];
    patient.geburtsdatum = [patientenGeburtsdatum objectAtIndex:i];
    patient.weiblich = [patientenWeiblich objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *patientenWeiblich = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NO, NO, NO , nil];
```

You can't put primitive types into NSArray. In your case compiler is silent just because `NO` is 0 which is effectively `nil`. So, you get an empty NSArray.

You should wrap them with `NSNumber` first:

```
NSArray *patientenWeiblich = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@(NO), @(NO), @(NO) , nil];
```

And afterwards get the value with:

```
[[patientenWeiblich objectAtIndex:i] boolValue];
```

Comment: The clang documents show that the parentheses are unnecessary for YES and NO.

Comment: @trudyscousin indeed. It's just a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a bool value as is. Instead use @(NO). That should work.

Answer (score 0):

`NO` is not an object but you need to store objects inside of an array. So
use `[NSNull null]` or `@(NO`) instead of `NO`.